# How can I invert a binary tree in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, binary

how can i flip over binary tree?  I recently came across this problem, and all my attempts to do it adequately failed. initial tree shown below.

```
     4
   /   \
  2     7
 / \   / \
1   3 6   9

     4
   /   \
  7     2
 / \   / \
9   6 3   1
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
 *     this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {TreeNode} root
 * @return {TreeNode}
 */
var invertTree = function(root) {
    
};
```

Comment: `[root.left, root.right] = [root.right, root.left]` then do same for children

Comment: Simply swap left node with right node, try my binary tree class which comes with build it function reverse(). Refer links -
Class - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree
Documentation - https://dsinjs.github.io/binary-tree/#reverse

Answer (score 9):

It will be easier with recursive method in js using DFS (depth first search) and simply swap the nodes

```
    const trav = (currNode) => {
      if (currNode === null) {
        return;
      }
      const temp = currNode.lNode;
      currNode.lNode = currNode.rNode;
      currNode.rNode = temp;
      trav(currNode.lNode);
      trav(currNode.rNode);
    };
    trav(root);
    return root;
```

For more refer to the class I wrote for more interesting methods -
Class - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree
Documentation for reverse() method - https://dsinjs.github.io/binary-tree/#reverse

Comment: Seems like it would be more clear to swap the values after you traverse rather than before.

Answer (score 3):

For every node with at least one child, you can swap its children by making the node's `.left` value equal to the node's `.right` value, and the node's `.right` value equal to the (old) `.left` value. Once you've swapped the children, you can then see whether you have to do the same process for the subtrees rooted at the children nodes by recursively calling your `invertTree()` function. If a node doesn't have either left or right children, then you're at a leaf, meaning you can return the passed in node (as no further child swapping is required).

```js
function Node(val, left, right) {
  this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val);
  this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left);
  this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right);
}

const invertTree = function(root) {
  if(!root || !root.left && !root.right) { // base case
    return root;
  }
  
  const oldLeft = root.left;
  root.left = root.right;
  root.right = oldLeft;
  invertTree(root.left);
  invertTree(root.right);
  return root;
};


const tree = new Node(4, new Node(2, new Node(1), new Node(3)), new Node(7, new Node(6), new Node(9)));
console.log(invertTree(tree));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just recurse through the tree, mutating it with the left and right sides swapped if they exist.

```js
const invertTree = tree => {
    if (!(tree?.left && tree?.right)) {
        return tree
    }

    [tree.right, tree.left] = [invertTree(tree.left), invertTree(tree.right)]
}
```

Comment: 1 up for 1 liners.

Comment: this would work for only Fully Balanced Binary Tree. Not for any Binary Tree

Answer (score 0):

A recent edit to an answer bubbled this older question to the top, and I didn't see any simple answer that treated the data immutably.  So here is one quick function:

```js
const invertTree = (t) =>
  t === null ? null : new TreeNode (t .val, invertTree (t .right), invertTree (t .left))

const tree = new TreeNode (4, new TreeNode (2, new TreeNode (1), new TreeNode (3)), new TreeNode (7, new TreeNode (6), new TreeNode (9)))

const inverted = invertTree (tree)

// Note that the original is not mutated:
console .log ('Original: ', JSON .stringify (tree, null, 4))
console .log ('Inverted: ', JSON .stringify (inverted, null, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>function TreeNode (val, left, right) {this .val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val); this .left = (left === undefined ? null : left); this .right = (right === undefined ? null : right)}</script>
```

In our base case, the node is `null` and we return `null`.  Otherwise we construct a new node with the same `val`, and with recursive calls to `invertTree` passing the right node and the left node in that order so that the new tree has them swapped.

If it were up to me, I would not use a constructor function (nor a `class`) for this but a simple data constructor:

```js
const node = (val, left, right) => ({val, left: left || null, right: right || null})

const invertTree = (t) =>
  t == null ? null : node (t .val, invertTree (t .right), invertTree (t .left))

const tree = node (4, node (2, node (1), node (3)), node (7, node (6), node (9)))
const inverted = invertTree (tree)

console .log ('Original: ', JSON .stringify (tree, null, 4))
console .log ('Inverted: ', JSON .stringify (inverted, null, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function invertTree(node) {
    if (node && node.left) {
        let left = node.left;
        node.left = node.right;
        node.right = left;
        invertTree(node.right);
        invertTree(node.left);
    }
    return node;
}

const n = {value: 5, left: {left: 5, right: 6 }, right: {left: 1, right: 2}};
console.log(invertTree(n))
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem like this. Try this algorithm.
I know it's late, but it will help others

```js
 const node = {
    value: 1,
    left: {
      value: 2,
      left: { value: 4  },
       right: { value: 5  }   
    },
    right: {
       value: 3,
       left: { value: 6},
       right: { value: 7  }
    }
 }

invertFree = (node) => {
    if (node) {
        const newNode = { value: node.value }
        if (node.right) {
            newNode.left = invertFree(node.right)
        }
        if (node.left) {
           newNode.right = invertFree(node.left)
        }
        return newNode
    }
}

console.log(invertFree(node))
```